# When can JavaScript characters take up 2 code units and what exactly IS a code unit?

Tags: javascript

I read today:

> The length property of a string counts the number of "code units" in a string. In the majority of cases, one character uses one code unit, but some of the rarely used characters take up two

Please can somebody explain exactly what a "code unit" is, preferably in a good level of depth, and where I can find what characters fit into the category of 2? Preferably a table resource if you know of one somewhere!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, it is not answer, but i know from where did you copy paste the answer.
"Jon Duckket", javascript and jquery interactive front end development book, right?

Comment: this is a question not an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few characters that can be distinctly represented by 8 bits of data, so there are encodings that map characters to multiple bytes. Like in the various Unicode encodings, a character can be 1 byte or multiple bytes in a sequence.

So a code point is a term for a grouping of 1 or more bytes that represent a single character.

The characters `"世界"` in an encoding like UTF-8 for example will each take multiple bytes, but the string in JavaScript will return a `.length` of `2`.

```js
var s = "世界";

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = "char | index | base-10 | binary\n"
document.querySelector("pre").textContent +="-------------------------------------\n"

for (var i=0; i < s.length; i++) {
  var cc = s.charCodeAt(i);
  document.querySelector("pre").textContent += 
         s[i] + "   |   " + i + "   |  " + cc + "  |  " + to_binary(cc) + "\n";
}

function to_binary(n) {
    return pad(n.toString(2)).replace(/(\d{8})/g, "$1 ");
}

function pad(s) {
  return ("0000000" + s).slice(-(s.length + (8-(s.length%8))));
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

So you can see that the `.charCodeAt()` calls reveal a numeric representation that wouldn't even come close to fitting into 8 bits of data. As such, the characters are represented by multiple bytes.

Comment: Also see here for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Code_unit

Comment: @sixfingeredman ‘in unicode will each take multiple bytes’ No. Unicode is not a byte encoding. I think you mean something like UTF-8.

Comment: @Biffen: Aren't the various UTF-n encodings under the Unicode umbrella? Or am I confused about that?

Comment: @sixfingeredman Yeah, they are. But Unicode itself is not an encoding in the sense that it can represent text using bytes (it can be said to ‘encode’ characters to codepoints).

Comment: @Biffen: I can update, but is there anything Unicode represents besides character encodings? What I wrote was *"the various Unicode encodings"*. I didn't say Unicode itself was an encoding. So I'm not entirely understanding what you're getting at.

Comment: @sixfingeredman  Yes, Unicode does *a lot* more than assign codepoints to characters, but dealing with bytes in any way is *not* one of them. Saying that ‘"世界" in unicode will each take multiple bytes’ makes it sound like Unicode *itself* can determine how a string will be ‘turned into’ bytes, but it most certainly can't. UTF-n (and others) can.

Comment: @Biffen: Oh, I see the *"in Unicode"* now. I was looking at my first paragraph. I'll update.